# Generic F# type with non-generic constructor

Tags: generics, f#

Is there some way to have a generic type with a parameterless constructor that creates a non-generic instance? Non-compiling example:

```
type Child<'T>() = class end

type Parent<'T>(c:Child<'T>) =
   new() = Parent(Child<unit>()) // ERROR: This code is less generic than required by 
                                 // its annotations because the explicit type variable
                                 // 'T' could not be generalized. It was constrained to be 'unit'.
```

I want a non-generic value in order to avoid the value restriction and also because I want to use `'T` with overloading (e.g. overloading on `Parent<int>` vs. `Parent<bool>` etc.).

I think it is probably not possible and I need to find a different way to model things. But maybe somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible - when calling the constructor of a generic object, the caller can always specify any type argument he wants. This is similar to calling a static method - the caller always can specify a type:

```
let a = new Parent<Foo>()
let b = Parent<Foo>.Bar
```

The constructor in a type `Parent<'T>` always returns a value of type `Parent<'T>`, so you cannot avoid using the type `'T` as part of the type signature. However, a static method can have a different return type.

Perhaps you could use a static method instead of constructor?

```
type Child<'T>() = class end
type Parent<'T>(c:Child<'T>) =
    static member New() = Parent(Child<unit>())
```

Then you can write:

```
let a = Parent.New()
let b = Parent<Foo>.New() // You can specify type parameter, but it is ignored, 
                          // because return type is always 'Parent<unit>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Too be honest I think you are really looking for an optional parameter.

```
type Parent<'T>(?c:Child<'T>) = class 

    end
```

Of course this requires they specify the type but is that so bad?

```
let p = Parent<int>()
```